# Prevent last divider character being rendered in loop

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
if(hasRows($resultC)){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($resultC)) {
        $mescategories = '<span><a href="' . CalRoot . 
            '/index.php?com=searchresult&amp;t=' . $row[0] . 
            '" rel="tag" class="eventMain">' . cOut($row[1]) . '</a></span> | ' ;
        echo $mescategories; 
    }//end while
}//end if
```

The rendered output looks like:

```
cat 1 | cat 2 | cat 3 | cat 4 |
```

How do I prevent the last `|` character being rendered.

Comment: You should look into using implode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$catArray = array();
if(hasRows($resultC)){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($resultC)){
        array_push($catArray, '<span><a href="' . CalRoot . '/index.php?com=searchresult&amp;t=' . $row[0] . '" rel="tag" class="eventMain">' . cOut($row[1]) . '</a></span>');
    }//end while
    echo implode('|', $catArray);
}//end if
```

Comment: Shouldn't the "glue" be before the string pieces for implode? http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: I think you're correct, but I referenced the O'Reilly Cuckoo book, and it has it reversed. I'll edit.

Comment: Ah, look at the note in the online description. They can be in any order.

Comment: From the php doc: "implode() can, for historical reasons, accept its parameters in either order. For consistency with explode(), however, it may be less confusing to use the documented order of arguments."

Comment: @JonathanM - np, it seems it wasn't really necessary by the comment trail, but it is more consistant with the documentation declaration.

Comment: I'd bring `catArray` inside the conditional.

Answer (score 3):

You could count the number of rows using `mysql_num_rows($resultC)`, and have a counter on your loop. Alternatively, the way I'd do it is something like:

```
if(hasRows($resultC)){
    // Create an empty array
    $links = array( );

    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($resultC)){
        // Add each text link to the array
        $links[] = '<span><a href="' . CalRoot . '/index.php?com=searchresult&amp;t=' . $row[0] . '" rel="tag" class="eventMain">' . cOut($row[1]) . '</a></span>' ;    
    }
    // "Glue" the array back together using implode, with the separator between each.
    echo implode(' | ', $links );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$i = 0; //set before while loop
$i++; //inserted into while loop
if ($i != mysql_num_rows($resultC) ) { //inserted into while loop
  $mescategories .= " | " ;
}
```

mysql_num_rows will tell how many rows there are in the query, and then will append the pipe character for each row except the last one.

EDIT: I think the $i++ should come before the if statement, actually.

Comment: This is very confusing as you have a single code block in your answer, consisting of individual snippets of code that are to go in different places.

Answer (score 2):

How about putting in a conditional statement.  Count the size of the row and if $count=$maxcount then don't echo the "|" character.

Answer (score 1):

I have not checked your formatting. Just added a "first" variable.

```
if(hasRows($resultC)){
    $first = true;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($resultC)){
        $mescategories = ' '.($first ? "":"|").' <span><a href="' . CalRoot . '/index.php?com=searchresult&amp;t=' . $row[0] . '" rel="tag" class="eventMain">' . cOut($row[1]) . '</a></span> ' ;
        echo $mescategories; 
        $first = false;
    }//end while
}//end if
```

Comment: adding a space to the variable

Answer (score 1):

try

```
if(hasRows($resultC)){
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($resultC)){
    $spaceline  =($i>0) ? '|' : '';
    $mescategories = '<span><a href="' . CalRoot . '/index.php?com=searchresult&amp;t=' . $row[0] . '" rel="tag" class="eventMain">' . cOut($row[1]) . '</a></span>' ;
    $i++;
    echo $spaceline.$mescategories; 

    }//end while
}//end if
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do

`echo substr($mescategories, 0, -1);`

instead of `echo $mescategories`
you let it put | after every instance and then delete the last char

else if you need to know the last key of an array you use:

```
end($array);
$lastKey = key($array);
```

but don't forget to reset before you do things with it

```
reset($array);
```